# Auto populate lookup in Power Pages page

Tags: liquid, fetchxml, dataverse

I am new to Power pages. I have created a custom web page with a lookup box that I would like to connect to a dataverse table.

If I create a basic form then the lookup of course is based on the relationship, but I don't know what code to use to get the same result in custom page.